# Should an utility class hold only one method?

Tags: java, static

I'm wondering if it's good practice to have a static utility class with only one method.

The method needs to be used throughout the application domain, and it looks like this:

```
public final class SomeClass {

    private SomeClass () {}

    public static int makeSpecificCalculation(int x, int y) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Is this best practice, having an utilities class with only *one* utility? Or should I just give it its own instance class, even if it never grows beyond this?

Comment: Is it good practice to have a toolbox with one tool? Depends on what you use the tool(box) for. If you only have the one function, why not? But if you have 10 utility classes each with a single static function, then you might want to think about putting them together. Just my opinion.

Comment: I'm not sure of what you are asking ? Are you asking about having a "static" class (no instance of the class) or are you asking about the fact of having only one method ?

Comment: @Gaël Both really. I'm aware that static utility classes are sometimes considered bad, but can be useful if they aggregate a group of related functions. But I'm wondering if this applies to only a one-function toolbox, or if it is a code smell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to avoid really many static classes each having a single utility method. However in a small and specialized project sometimes happens that there is only one commonly used method that could be extracted into static class. If it is a complex method, it can also be split into multiple private methods inside that class.

Most likely your single method class will get more utility methods over time.